# dbpedia spotlight web service in java

Tags: java, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I want to get the `dbpedia` links of the entities from text. I have seen that `DBpedia spotlight` is the best method. So i tried it with `curl` commands and output looks good.
I am processing the text using the `DBpedia Spotlight Web Service` with `HttpClient` in `Java` as given in this link http://hi.baidu.com/shirleyzzzhen/item/e757e17bfdf98125d6a89c00 . I want to process millions of documents daily. Is it possible to process my documents by this method? Is there any daily limit for accessing the web service?

Comment: **Stop** spamming links to this question in the comments of other questions. That is completely unacceptable behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want to process millions of documents daily. Is it possible to process my documents by this method?"

Yes, but I think it is a good idea to use url parameter instead of text. E.g. http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/annotate?url=http://edition.cnn.com/2015/04/29/asia/nepal-earthquake/index.html

"Is there any daily limit for accessing the web service?"

No, there is not. But keep in mind that spotlight.dbpedia.org is a demo service.  I recommend to have your own instance in order to process it.